# Imageio in python : compressing gif

Tags: python, python-imageio

Is there a way to compress the gif while making it with `imageio` in `python`? I am making gif with about 200 images and the final file is 30MB. I would prefer if it is 5-10 MB. Anyway the images are mono-colour so should be fine to compress. Is there a tool I can use or specify it with `imageio` ?

Here is my code to make gif :

```py
    import os
    import imageio as io
    import re
    
    # Key to sort the file_names in order
    numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
    def numericalSort(value):
        parts = numbers.split(value)
        parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
        return parts
    

    file_names = sorted((fn for fn in os.listdir('.') if fn.startswith('timestamp_')), key = numericalSort)
    

    # GIF writer
    with io.get_writer('output_gif.gif', mode='I', duration=0.1) as writer:
        for filename in file_names:
            image = io.imread(filename)
            writer.append_data(image)
```

Comment: hey, i have added my code

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: no :( i actually just made gif out of every $i^{th}$ frame to reduce the size. can  you suggest a way for me?

Comment: https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif << this open source tool written in C# compresses gifs pretty well. maybe there is some algorithm you can port to python.

Answer (score 9):

Faced the very same problem, I've created a wrapper for [gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) library called [pygifsicle](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/pygifsicle) and one can use it as follows:

```py
from pygifsicle import optimize
optimize("path_to_my_gif.gif")
```

As every other package on pip, one can install it by running:

```sh
pip install pygifsicle
```

A full example for using this library is available in the [imageio documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#optimizing-a-gif-using-pygifsicle).

While installing pygifsicle you will automatically install also, if you are on MacOS, the gifsicle library using [Brew](https://brew.sh/). For the other systems, a step-by-step guide will be provided, which it basically just asks to install the library via apt-get on Debian / Ubuntu (since it seems a good idea to not ask for sudo within the package setup):

```sh
sudo apt-get install gifsicle
```

Or on windows you can [install one of the available ports](https://eternallybored.org/misc/gifsicle/).

Comment: Hey, cool solution, I have not tested this yet but I will try it, thanks a lot for making this!

Comment: hi, i actually noticed that this is increasing, rather than decreasing my file size...
Initally, test.gif==13M. After running `pygifsicle.optimize("test.gif")`, test.gif==23M

Comment: Hello @AviVajpeyi, pygifsicle offers bindings to the [gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) library, which often is able to compress the images. In my test cases, the library is always effective, but I suppose that there are cases where the compression algorithm fails. I would suggest you open a pull request with this case [in their github repository](https://github.com/kohler/gifsicle).

Comment: @LucaCappelletti how to add other gifsice options like `lossy` to `optimize` function?

Comment: Hello @JimsonKannantharaJames, please do open an issue on the documentation of the repository for this sort of question, so that we may explore it there.

Comment: Holy guacamoly, this saved my like 60%! Much wow ;) seriously, the compression is quite good.

Comment: Do say thanks to the authors at gifsicle, mine is just a wrapper!

Comment: FileNotFoundError: The gifsicle library was not found on your system.
On MacOS it is automatically installed using brew when you use the pip install command.
On other systems, like Linux systems and Windows, it prompts the instructions to be followed for completing the installation.
You can learn more on how to install gifsicle on the gifsicle and pygifsicle documentation.

Comment: Yeah, @FeraruSilviuMarian that is the extremely explicative error that my library provides when you do not have the Gifsicle library installed. In my answer, there are the instructions for Ubuntu, macOS and Windows. What problem are you encountering? Possibly you should ask a question about it.

Comment: It is increasing the gif size. Can we pass any additional parameters to this function?

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to resize and reduce the quality of an image before you create the gif.

```
from PIL import Image
# Resizing
image.resize((x, y), Image.ANTIALIAS)
# Reducing Quality
quality_val = 90
image.save(filename, 'JPEG', quality=quality_val)
```

Full code for turning images into compressed gif

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
x = 250
y = 250
fp_in = 'path/to/images'
fp_in = 'path/to/gif/output'
q = 50 # Quality
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f).resize((x,y),Image.ANTIALIAS) for f in sorted(glob.glob(fp_in))] 
img.save(fp=fp_out, format='GIF', append_images=imgs,quality=q, 
         save_all=True, duration=15, loop=0, optimize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the purpose (e.g., website animation), HTML5 can be your friend as it supports looping, autoplay, and video compression codecs.

```html
<video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```